# "Side-By-Side" configuration is incorrect in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-rt

I'm trying to install the Application Certification Kit for WinRT. So far, I got everything else for the SDK installed and have Visual Studio 2012 and friends, but I can't get this certification kit to install. It continually says

> The application has failed to start because it's side-by-side
>   configuration is incorrect....

It says to check the eventlog, but I see no events relating to this.

The program in question is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/jj572486 (the download on the right)

What could be missing? I've heard this is caused by C++ redistributables not being installed, but how can I tell which one? And wouldn't a C++ development environment have taken care of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the very misleading wording on that page, it's actually an ARM only executable. I opened it in ILSpy, which indicated that it was a pure .Net executable, but also targeted for ARM only. Despite the optimistic wording on that page, it is a WinRT(tablet)-only executable.

Comment: Well it does state "To self-test your app ***on*** Windows RT..." and under Supported Operating Systems for the **Windows App Certification Kit for Windows RT** it clearly states **Windows RT** (unlike for the Windows SDK). There's also this useful Note: "The Windows SDK for Windows 8 cannot be installed directly on the ARM architecture. You can install the Windows SDK on an x86 or x64 platform to build applications that target the ARM architecture, **and *then* use the Windows App Certification Kit for Windows RT download to test the app *on that platform***.

Answer (score 1):

You miss a Visual C++ runtime.

Run the Command prompt [with admin rights](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token) and run this command:

```
SxsTrace Trace -logfile:SxsTrace.etl
```

Now run the programm which causes the SideBySide error.

Go back to the command prompt press ENTER to generate the **SxsTrace.etl**. Now type this:

```
sxstrace Parse -logfile:SxSTrace.etl -outfile:SxSTrace.txt
```

Now open the SxSTrace.txt trace and look which VC++ runtime is missing.

If you are unsure, please upload the complete SxSTrace.txt

Comment: See my answer. Turns out it's actually ARM-only